# doing something after Laravel's http client exception

Tags: laravel, http, exception, try-catch, guzzle

I need to access to an online file and reading is content, but if for some reason the file isn't available due network/server problem ill use a local version stored on my server.

For doing that I've written this simple code:

```php
$response = Http::timeout(2)->get('http.site/file.json');
```

And I add this for checking if all is ok:

```php
if($response->successful()){
    $list = $response->body();
} else {
    $list = file_get_contents(asset('storage/list.json'));
}
```

But if I have a problem (for testing I just add a not correct address) of connection an exception is thrown and I cannot go into "else" part.

So I add a "`try, catch`":

```php
try{
    $response = Http::timeout(2)->get('http.site/file.json');            
    return $response->body();
}catch (Exception $ex) {
    return  file_get_contents(asset('storage/pharmaciesList.json'));
}
```

which is the correct way to treat this kind of code, and is it correct using a try catch without taking care of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's the right way, every function that could throw an exception should be enclosed in a try catch block. Otherwise (you said you're using Laravel) you can handle that exception in the exception handler.